# OpenGL - How to Jump in a Single TRIANGLE_STRIP without affecting Texturing?

Tags: opengl, geometry, textures, gaps-and-islands, gl-triangle-strip

If one puts the same vertex A into a triangle strip several times, then takes another vertex B and puts this one several times into the triangle strip also (the amount depending on the triangle orientation one wants to continue with), then one effectively can have two separate triangle strips to be rendered with only one draw call (the first containing all triangles before vertex A and the second consisting of all triangles after vertex B).

My question:

I am afraid, even though the complete triangle strip draw call will draw a geometrically simply connected mesh, I will encounter problems when attempting to texture the mesh due to the jumps in between. I am not quite there yet, so I cannot test it. Is my assumption correct?
Is my jumping in the triangle strip at any rate a valid technique in the "drawing meshes" industry? Is there any way to texture the result appropriately, or an equivalent better behaving alternative to the jumping?

Answer (score 3):

Consider a 'mesh' consisting of a triangle subdivided into 4 similar triangles:

```
      2
       /\
      /  \
   1 /____\3
    /\    /\
   /  \  /  \
0 /____\/4___\5
```

Assume CCW (glFrontFace) winding, the triangles: `{0,4,1}, {1,4,3}, {3,2,1}` are encoded as a strip: `{0,4,1,3,2}`. The trick is adding the triangle: `{4,5,3}` by adding degenerate (zero-area) triangles, while maintaining the correct winding. In short:

`{0,4,1,3,2,2,3,3,5,4}`, adds the zero-area triangles: `{3,2,2}, {2,2,3}, {3,3,5}`.

This adds a negligible amount of extra geometry for a larger mesh, provided that efficient mesh [striping](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=triangle%20mesh%20striping&sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is used.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing there. So it is a valid technique after all. But what about texturing that "mesh"?

Comment: I assume your texture coordinates (vertex attributes) correspond to the same vertices, and therefore use the same indices. I'm not sure what the problem would be?

Comment: Sorry, I guess the problem is rather my low experience with texturing meshes in general.

Answer (score 2):

Rasterizers draw the area of a triangle. A "triangle" that has two points that are the same has no area. Therefore, there is no area of the triangle to render.

Degenerate triangles (the technical term for triangles where two of the points are the same) are a common technique for connecting multiple strips. This is typically done in the index array by just adding more indices; nothing about the actual topology of the mesh needs to change.

Comment: Does that imply that in an attempt to texture that mesh I would have to offer snippets of texture for every triangle with manually set texture coordinates to each and every vertex (skipping those zero area ones)?
I was somewhat hoping for an automatic texture wrapping solution...

Comment: `glTexGen` provides on the fly texture coord generation. This is a depracated feature though. For precomputing the coords, see the math for all different modi here: http://opengl.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_glTexGen